# Download Img after long press on the image in, objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c

How to Download Img after long press on the image in objective-c?

Comment: show your tried code

Comment: Download Img - you want to show in image or you want to save in somewhere else

Comment: check this github code https://github.com/theniceboy/HoldToSaveImage

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it may solve your problem.

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *lpHandler = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleHoldGesture:)];
lpHandler.minimumPressDuration = 1; //seconds
lpHandler.delegate = self;
//imageView - replace for your instance/variable name
[imageView addGestureRecognizer:lpHandler];
}

- (void) handleHoldGesture:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
if(UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan == gesture.state)
{
// Called on start of gesture, do work here
UIImage* imageToSave = [imageView image]; // alternatively, imageView.image

// Save it to the camera roll / saved photo album
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(imageToSave, nil, nil, nil);

}

if(UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged == gesture.state)
{
    // Do repeated work here (repeats continuously) while finger is down
}

if(UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded == gesture.state)
{
    // Do end work here when finger is lifted
}

}
```